# Can I install Kali linux with out Ethernet card

Tags: linux, wifi, system-installation, kali-linux, ethernet

I want to install Kali linux on my Laptop, but I don't have a Ethernet card. It is possible to install Kali with out Ethernet or with wifi interface ??

Answer (score 1):

Linux does support wifi adapters.  We can't foresee the future but most adapters should work fine.

Why don't you install it and address specific issues as they arise, if they do.

Comment: When it do the detecting of network Hardware at the first part of Installation it shows this msg : no Ethernet card was detected. If you know the name of the driver needed.. You can select it from the list. But the Problem is, I don't have a Ethernet card on my Laptop. So it is possible to use the wifi interface instead of Ethernet?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have certain drivers for the hardware you are using. Even if you skip the steps it would most likely to prompt you for the missing wifi drivers. you can skip that too but you'll face a dead-end at the archive mirror selection process. 
I'll try to download the drivers in USB and see if that works...

Comment: We can also use a Smartphone as Modem, its work.